# Any progress in Using ROS in C#?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have searched the community for some one who had successfully used Ros in C# but i didn't find anyone!

Actually I have to write an API for a commercial Robotic Arm in linux environment which is only have a C# SDK , so i am using monoDevelop for writing C# codes in linux! but according to the fact that our robot is completely based On ROS i have to find a way to communicate with my C# based Arm Controller! currently i am writing a network based protocol for this purpose, but i am still looking for a better way!

So any suggestion would be appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33225/any-progress-in-using-ros-in-c#?/) by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 717 on 2012-05-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on 2012-06-06**:
PLEASE let me know if you have any success with making C# and ROS work together for full ROS functionality.....this would be fantastic for all of us!! When you get this to work, please consider publishing it as part of the ROS repositories so we can all have access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is now a C# api, available see: http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscs

---

Originally posted by [st](https://answers.ros.org/users/2686/st/) with karma: 86 on 2012-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using a very simple communication layer between your C# program and a ROS bridge as you seem to be doing it is probably the easiest solution.

I know about one application that is using ROS in C#, [streamvis](http://code.google.com/p/streamvis/). As far as I know, it uses roscpp via C#'s foreign function interface.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-05-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3